# c# Auto login to sprint

Tags: c#, .net

I have a project where I am trying to login to sprint and then do some screen scraping to get data about the different lines that the company controls.  I have tried passing the cookies that are provided by the initial website call in the initial HttpWebRequest form post, but I do not get any cookies back that will denote user or session or anything.  In fact, if I then try to use the WebClient class to get the landing page, the response url that I get back is the login page.

I think it is due to the fact that when you login, you get redirected to a page that does some processing and then redirects you to the landing page.  I am passing in correct credentials and don't know where it is failing.  Can anyone help me so that I do not need to use Watin or any other browser control to scrape that data as that will be too slow.

Comment: Update:  I was able to login successfully and get to the intermediate page.  This page is populated with iframes that I am guessing at this point add to the cookies needed by the site.  I run some code to call out to these pages with all existing cookies and actually get 4 new cookies which I then add to the collection.  However, when I try to access the landing page with all of the cookies, it still requires me to login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/).

It is normally for website testing, but you easily use it for your situation.

It allows you to launch a browser and programmatically control mouse clicks and keyboard presses to do exactly what you need.

You also run xpath on the HTML to read data, or even run custom javascript on pages if you need to get more complicated.

Comment: Selenium is great, but it doesn't satisfy my needs.  What I need is to get the html without rendering the page as I need to get information about 50,000 different lines across different accounts within a specific time period.  To accomplish this, I need to thread the application to crawl as many websites as possible.  Also, rendering the page will take too long and will not allow me to accomplish my goal.  I'm trying to do this without actually opening a browser and only using WebRequests and WebResponses.

Comment: Well, it sounds like it is going to be some serious hacking in firebug/etc. to get what you want.  Have you considered using Selenium for the first couple pages: login, etc. and for the 50,000 line page pass Selenium's cookies over to HttpWebRequest for the pages with large data?  And just checking, does sprint not have an API at all?

Comment: By using Seleniums WebDriver I was able to get the cookies needed to gain access via HttpWebRequests.  Thank you!!